# Web service en el servidor no me deja consultarlo desde aplicacion movil

Tags: php, android, webservice

Tengo un problema con un web service, mi web service lo coloque en mi servidor con un usuario que tiene privilegios de lectura y consulta y mi base de datos, si pongo en mi explorador web la siguiente url:

> www.sitioweb.org.mx/archivoconsulta.php?dato1=luis&dato2=Lopez

si coloco esto en mi navegador google, firefox o internet explorar me devuelve la información de la siguiente forma

{"sesion":[{"id_user":"1","nombre":"Luis","apellido":"Lopez","direccion":"Ciudad de Mexico"}]}

pero si ejecuto la consulta a mi web service desde mi aplicacion movil, me da **error al conectar con el servidor**

asi tengo el codigo para conectar mi web service con la aplicación:

```
String url = "https://www.sitioweb.org.mx/archivoconsulta.php?dato1="+editext1+"&dato2="+edittext2;
            jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
            request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

No entiendo porque no puedo conectarme al web service desde un dispositivo movil.

Error que me da al intentar conectarme:

> I/servidor: Error de conexion: com.android.volley.ParseError:
>   org.json.JSONException: Value 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Logcat cuando se muestra el error:

```
2019-02-18 14:04:04.047 11592-11592/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
2019-02-18 14:04:04.070 1958-1958/com.android.inputmethod.latin I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
2019-02-18 14:04:07.262 1365-1395/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 6143341 , only wrote 5990400
2019-02-18 14:04:09.401 1972-2252/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x91012260: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9f75fe50)
2019-02-18 14:04:09.404 1365-1394/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 5990629 , only wrote 5990400
2019-02-18 14:04:09.476 1958-1958/com.android.inputmethod.latin W/InputMethodService: Window size has been changed. This may cause jankiness of resizing window: -1 -> -2
2019-02-18 14:04:09.478 1958-4643/com.android.inputmethod.latin D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae6059c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae603860)
2019-02-18 14:04:10.846 11592-11592/com.example.seccin15hibrida I/servidor: Error de conexion: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2019-02-18 14:04:10.913 11592-11628/com.example.seccin15hibrida D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f71ff80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x8e2ea600)
2019-02-18 14:04:11.081 11592-11628/com.example.seccin15hibrida D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f71ff80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x8e2ea600)
2019-02-18 14:04:13.605 1365-1395/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 6391810 , only wrote 6192000
2019-02-18 14:04:14.369 1731-1731/system_process W/WindowManager: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@4dd432d
2019-02-18 14:05:00.029 1972-2252/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x91012260: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9f75fe50)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi metodo onErrorResponse:

```
@Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al conectar al servidor: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("servidor","Error de conexion: "+error);
    }
```

Mi metodo onResponse:

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("sesion");
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try{
            jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(0);
            nombreBD = (jsonObject.getString("nombre_usuario"));
            passwordBD = (jsonObject.getString("password"));
            claveBD = (jsonObject.getString("clave"));
            rolBD = (jsonObject.getString("rol"));
            empresaBD = (jsonObject.getString("empresa"));

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (nombreBD.equals("No registrado") || passwordBD.equals("No registrado")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Los datos son incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(passwordBD.equals(passwordCaja)){

            registrarUsuario(nombreBD, passwordBD,"master",rolBD, empresaBD, box);

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La contraseña es incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

2019-02-18 16:31:29.117 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida I/servidor: Error de conexion: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2019-02-18 16:31:29.117 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2019-02-18 16:31:29.118 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:90)
2019-02-18 16:31:29.118 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:143)
2019-02-18 16:31:29.118 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
2019-02-18 16:31:29.118 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
2019-02-18 16:31:29.122 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err: Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2019-02-18 16:31:29.123 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
2019-02-18 16:31:29.123 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
2019-02-18 16:31:29.123 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
2019-02-18 16:31:29.123 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:85)
2019-02-18 16:31:29.123 19423-19423/com.example.seccin15hibrida W/System.err:   ... 3 more
```

Comment: Agrega el error que te está dando, debes tener una excepción en el Logcat. Por las dudas confirmá que edittext1 y edittext2 sean strings y no los EditText en sí.

Comment: @Juan Ya agregue el error del Logcat y si he revisado y mis cajas de texto los convierto a String, tambien esta confirmado porque de forma local permite conectarme con una base de datos de prueba

Comment: Fijate de agregar a la pregunta algunas lineas mas de la excepción. Tiene que haber una linea que dice donde se está produciendo (tratá de indicar cual es esa linea en el codigo agregado a la pregunta). También agregá los handlers de success y error que deben ser metodos de tu clase (onResponse y onErrorResponse).

Comment: antes de hacer el request podrias hacer uhn Log.i("url",url); para ver como va formada la url, creo que lleva espacios en blanco en la concatenacion de las variables

Comment: @Juan Ya agregue mas código, pero no muestra como tal un error en una linea mas bien es en la consulta o recibir datos

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez ya revise pero todo parece bien, de echo con otra bd local no me da error

Comment: y seguro que es https? o sera http? en que sistema operativo tienes el webservices? pregunto para revisar al error.log de apache

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez si, todo es https, ya revise esas posibilidades

Comment: descarga https://insomnia.rest/download/ para tener de forma visual lo que re responde el servidor... cuando empece con las API REST no tenia idea de como ver lor errores y eso me ayudo

Comment: Dentro de onErrorResponse(VolleyError errro) pone error.printStackTrace() y agregá ese stack trace que tiene que dar mas detalle del error;

Comment: Prueba a mandarle una petición escrita a mano, algo así: `www.sitioweb.org.mx/archivoconsulta.php?dato1=luis&dato2=Lopez` y trata de mostrar en el log cat la respuesta convertida a cadena, no me convence mucho la forma en que manejas la respuesta, pero primero es ver si hay algo en la respuesta. ¿Tienes acceso al sitio remoto y potestad para revisar el código allí? ¿No requiere algún tipo de clave o autorización? Puedes revisar los logs del servidor también.

Comment: @Juan ya coloque los errores que me arrojo con el error.printStckTrace(), el error si no lei mal es este "com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Comment: @A.Cedano de echo esa consulta la muestro en un explorador y funciona, pero no se como mostrar el error en el logcat del servidor, si tengo acceso al panel, en explorador web no me marca ningun error me permite consultar sin problemas

Comment: El error no corresponde con la respuesta que dices tener , agrega que valor tienes en response cuando obtienes la petición. @EnriqueEspinosa

Comment: Para ver el texto que estás recibiendo cambia a un StringRequest en lugar de jsonObject. Y ahi podes recibir el string crudo y ver si realmente está llegando lo que pensas que viene.

Comment: Al perecer el servidor te está devolviendo este código: `21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3`, por algún motivo. ¿Probaste mandando desde Android una URL escrita a mano? A veces si tomas valores de textfield con espacios y demás y no estás parseando bien los datos en el servidor pueden ocurrir errores. En esa consulta desde la app el servidor no te está respondiendo un JSON, es lo que dice el mensaje *`"com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`*

Comment: @A.Cedano si esa cadena de caracteres no es un error, ayer revise y cuando yo recupero el texto de mis EditText para enviarlo, se envian a un archivo php que encripta mi contraseña en md5 no se porque me lo devuelve en la consulta si solamente lo envio para validar en la base de datos